# How to set constraints automatically adapt the different screen sizes in storyboard?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to set the constraints automatically adapt 4 , 4.7 , 5.5 inch in storyboard, buttons and views will be automatically adjusted the ratio while using different screen.However,now i'm confused to using Autolayout and sizeclass in xcode6, hoping someone could answer this problem or guide me to do this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why don't you get a look at some tutorial: https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=ios+size+classes+tutorial&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: Actually, I wanna set a calculator, I've seen a lot of tutorial but hardly mention this.

Comment: follow the link I posted... or you are looking for a tutorial that builds a calculator using size classes?

Comment: yes, coz I'm trying to set a calculator but the tutorial not enough to solve my problem.